# Static map with route in Image in windows phone 8.1

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, maps, google-maps-static-api

I am working with windows phone 8.1 [RT] map application , I want to show Map Image with route like [Google Static Map](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/static-maps/intro)

Is there any way create Image in Windows phone map ?
I have tried with Bing map , with I have no Bing map key ,So I can not find anything 
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

check https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff701724.aspx#

You will still need to have a Bing map key, but creating one for a mobile app is free.